# create new column based on other column but stripping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with an `id` column looking like this:

```
id                
A2015        
B2016         
C2017
```

I want two new columns as follows:

```
id         year       name  
A2015      2015       A Q
B2016      2016       B Q
C2017      2017       C Q
```

so the `year` column should take the four last characters of the `id` column and the `name` column should take all but the last four characters and add `Q`.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get these using string methods.

Get `year` by taking part of `id` string

```
In [60]: df['year'] = df['id'].str[1:]
```

And, get `name` by taking last four characters of `id` string and adding `' q'`

```
In [61]: df['name'] = df['id'].str[:-4] + ' Q'

In [62]: df
Out[62]:
      id  year name
0  A2015  2015  A Q
1  B2016  2016  B Q
2  C2017  2017  C Q
```

Comment: ah thanks. i was going the right way but instead of accessing via `df['id'].str` i did it via `str(df['id'])` which is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

```
    df['year'] = df['id'].apply(lambda v : v[1:])
    df['name'] = df['id'].apply(lambda v : v[0] + ' Q')
```

lambda functions are generally faster

Comment: Not necessarily @sachin, [string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) were written considering the speedups.